# php/xpath query: how to get content of div, that may have nested divs?

Tags: php, html, xpath

im trying to make a function that returns the inner HTML of a div with a spesific classname.
i searched around and people seem to say xpath query is the way to go.
this is what i got:

```
function getDivContent($html, $classname) {
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query('//div[class="'.$classname.'"]');
return $result;
}
```

but it only returns:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#3 (0) { }
```

anyone can spot the error?

EDIT: The solution:

```
function nodeContent($n, $outer=false) { 
    $d = new DOMDocument('1.0'); 
    $b = $d->importNode($n->cloneNode(true),true); 
    $d->appendChild($b); $h = $d->saveHTML(); 
    // remove outter tags 
    if (!$outer) $h = substr($h,strpos($h,'>')+1,-(strlen($n->nodeName)+4)); 
    return $h; 
} 

function getDivContentByClass($html, $class) {
    $query = "//div[@class='$class']";
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $result = $xpath->query($query);
    $data = nodeContent($result->item(0));
    return $data;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xpath's query function returns a NODEList, which is essentially an array of the results, even if there's only a single matching node.

```
return $result->item(0);
```

will return the first matching node only. To get the content, you can use `$result->item(0)->nodeValue`, which acts equivalently to .innerHTML.

Comment: i tried this, but i get this error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array and this is the code that provokes it `var_dump($result[0]->nodeValue);`

Comment: `nodeValue` doesn't act equivalently to `innerHTML` at all.

Comment: yeah i just figured out. i dont get the source code, seems like i only get the visible text inside the div :> what can i use